# flex: swfloader - flash file overlaps it's configured size

Tags: apache-flex, flash, swfloader

i'm using swfloader to load swf file in the middle of the screen using the following command:

`<mx:SWFLoader id="game_swf"  source="crazy_counting.swf" x="198" y="0" width="721" maxWidth="721" height="531" maxHeight="531" />`

now stage of the flash file takes the exact size that i stated by the flash file itself is overlapping the stage with some graphics. how i can i hide overlapped graphics ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved the issue by placing the swfloader inside a Container, for example a box. the flash graphics do not go out of the limits of the Container. i need also to sure that box to match the height and width of the swf.

Comment: please read the comments for konsumierer question, there is a bug and a workaround is written there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Flex 4 (nightly build 4.1.0.14607). A container such as Spark VGroup with it's property clipAndEnableScrolling set to "true" solved this problem for me.